# jq output true if element exists

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use jq to output a single boolean it a element exists in array:

`jq -e '.differences[] | .afterBlob.path | contains ("sandbox_app") or contains ("sandbox_cicd")'`

Input:

```
{
    "differences": [
        {
            "beforeBlob": {
                "blobId": "a9033f024bf",
                "path": "test1",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "afterBlob": {
                "blobId": "e27f2609943e",
                "path": "test1",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "changeType": "M"
        },
        {
            "beforeBlob": {
                "blobId": "ec669676314",
                "path": "test2",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "afterBlob": {
                "blobId": "38867b90873",
                "path": "test2",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "changeType": "M"
        },
        {
            "afterBlob": {
                "blobId": "ae8c5bdb690",
                "path": "sandbox_app/test3",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "changeType": "A"
        },
        {
            "afterBlob": {
                "blobId": "97819f382ad9",
                "path": "sandbox_cicd/test3",
                "mode": "100644"
            },
            "changeType": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Current Output:

```
false
false
true
true
```

How can i get the output to just be a single boolean.

I have tried using the 'any' function:

```
 jq -e '.differences[] | .afterBlob.path | contains ("sandbox_app") or contains ("sandbox_cicd") | any'
```

but get the following:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:46): Cannot iterate over boolean (false)
```

I have also tried wrapping the 'any' function around my statement. Is there a way for jq to just output a single boolean if value exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the current expression in an array, which can then be fed to `any`:

```
jq -e '[.differences[].afterBlob.path |
         contains ("sandbox_app") or contains ("sandbox_cicd")] | 
       any' foo.json
```

You can also write this using `map`:

```
jq -e '.differences | 
       map(.afterBlob.path | contains ("sandbox_app") or contains ("sandbox_cicd")) |
       any' foo.json
```

which is slightly longer, but you might find it more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

`any/2` allows for a considerably more efficient solution here than `any/0`:

```
any(.differences[]; 
    .afterBlob.path | contains ("sandbox_app") or contains ("sandbox_cicd") )
```